# What's wrong with my Seekbar? TAT

Tags: android, seekbar

guys,thanks for view my question(TAT)

i use SeekBar in a videoPlay app,on my device(XiaoMi4,api 23),it is ok.
but on other device(Nexus5 api 22,Nexus 6P,api 22),it looks like this:

[image]

here is my xml:

```
<SeekBar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                style="@style/MediaController_SeekBar"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/video_currentTime"
                android:id="@+id/video_seekBar"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/video_totalTime"/>
```

and @style/MediaController_SeekBar:

```
<style name="MediaController_SeekBar" parent="android:Widget.SeekBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/scrubber_progress_horizontal_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/scrubber_progress_horizontal_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">13dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">13dip</item>
    <item name="android:thumb">@drawable/scrubber_control_selector_holo</item>
    <item name="android:thumbOffset">16dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">16dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">16dip</item>
</style>
```

it is wrong on api< 23 device

i try to use default style,but it don't work

so,can u help me? thanks a lot!

Comment: provide some padding from bottom to seekbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting minHeight and Maxheight to some value on Seekbar .. Hope that will help

```
    android:maxHeight="40dp"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use dp for all instead of using dip